# how to use different model in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails App, there's  home_controller.rb, in which I'd like to use un-related table(User model). 
When I  access example.com/home/index, I'd like it to send message to 4th id person in User table.
I'm using mailboxer gem to send message.

I added these to home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
     receipt = User.find(4)
     receipt.send_message(receipt, "Body2", "subject2")
    end

end
```

in home model, it's totally empty.

It certainly sends message. But it sends  to 1st id person, who is current user.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the code to `send_message` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `send_message` method delivers email to the object that receives the method call, not the object in the first argument.  Try calling

```
receipt.send_message(receipt, "Body", "subject")
```

Comment: if I do that, User Id#2 sends message to itself. What if I want current user to send message to User ID#2??? and weird thing is that it doesn't deliver email to User ID#2 but current user's email address.

Comment: You're gonna need to post the code to `User#send_message` before I can help more.

Comment: Oh. I haven't done anything beside installing gem mailboxer, $ rails g mailboxer:install, $ rake db:migrate, and adding this line "acts_as_messageable" to my User model. That's it.

Comment: Check the docs for `acts_as_messageable`.  I've never used it.